# Getting 'active_link_to' to work properly with Pagination

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get `active_link_to` to work properly when I use `pagination`. I have 3 `nav-tabs` and they all work fine when selected, however, when I click on my pagination button to view more records my current nav-tab losses it's active status (style). What steps do I need to fix this issue?

Also 1 more minor issue if somebody doesn't mind. I'm using a `log-in` screen to get me to my main layout. When I log in, none of the `nav-tabs` are `active`. How do I render this? If I click on one of them it shows active but I want the 1st tab to display active by default. Again, I am using `active_link_to`.

Thank You.

TW

Here is my updated post with Code:

In my Gemfile I have

`gem kaminari`
`gem active_link_to`

In my `projects_controller.rb`

`@projects = Kaminari.paginate_array(@projects).page(params[:page]).per(10)`

In my `index.html.erb`

At the end of my page

`</table>`

`</div>`

`<%= paginate @projects %>`

In my `projects_helper.rb`

```
def active_link_to(text, link)
    content_tag(:li, :class => request.fullpath == link ? 'active' :nil) do 
      link_to text, link
    end 
end
```

In my Layout `application.html.erb`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><%= active_link_to("Active Projects", projects_path) %></li>
   ....
   ....
</ul>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code.

Comment: And please keep it to one question per thread, unless they are correlated in some way.

Comment: Yeah, I felt they were. active_link_to with pagination and default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to match the `link` to the `fullpath` entirely and your `fullpath` will sometimes contain a query string which will break the `fullpath == link` if you don't also include the query string in your `link`.

One possible solution would be to match a substring of the fullpath, something like this:

```
def active_link_to(text, link)
    content_tag(:li, :class => request.fullpath.starts_with?(link) ? 'active' :nil) do 
      link_to text, link
    end 
end
```

Or even using Ruby String's `[]` method to ask if a substring is present in the string:

```
def active_link_to(text, link)
    content_tag(:li, :class => request.fullpath[link].present? ? 'active' :nil) do 
      link_to text, link
    end 
end
```

You can also try a Gem that provides the method you want: https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to

It uses a more comprehensive method of matching paths.

Comment: I am using the Gem active_link_to. I tried both of your suggestions, still no luck. As soon as I click one of the pagination buttons, active link is gone.

Comment: If you're using the active_link_to Gem, why are you defining that method yourself? You're overriding it.

Comment: Still fairly new to Rails and Gems. So I probably saw some code dealing with active_link_to and just defined the method in the helper.

Comment: Just delete it and use active_link_to directly in your view inside of an li tag.

Comment: `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><%= active_link_to("Active Projects", projects_path) %></li>
   ....
   ....
</ul>`

Comment: That is the code I have in my layout view. Sorry about the sloppy copy/paste. It didn't work so I believe that is why I ended up defining the method.

Comment: Not an error but nothing happens. Active links are actually gone. Let me check my gems again to make sure it got nothing happened.

Comment: Yeah the Gem is in there and installed.

Comment: By "Active link are gone" do you mean the css "active" class never activates? Or the entire <a> tag is gone?

Comment: Sorry, yeah the css class never activates.

Comment: And you deleted the active_link_to method from your helper?

Comment: Yes, deleted the method.

Comment: Try using the alternate argument for active_link_to. Instead of passing in projects_path, pass in an array of [controller_name, action_name]. So for you it would be: ['projects', 'index'].

Comment: Error: cannot convert string into integer

Comment: Let me look at the docs and examples for the active_link_to gem a little bit more. Obviously, I need to go back to square one which is just get something working.

Comment: Oops sorry, my bad. It's better explained in the readme: https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to